# How to upload file in Selenium if input is created after javascript PYTHON

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, input, webdriver

By default there is no input in the site im visiting.
There is a script that runs and it is the only place where i am being able to find

```
<input type='file'/>

;
(function(e) {
    var c = {};
    c.fileapi = e("<input type='file'/>").get(0).files !== undefined;
    c.formdata = window.FormData !== undefined;
    e.fn.ajaxSubmit = function(g) {
        if (!this.length) {
            d("ajaxSubmit: skipping submit process - no element selected");
            return this
        }
        var f, u, j, l = this;
        if (typeof g == "function") {
            g = {
                success: g
            }
        }
        f = this.attr("method");
        u = this.attr("action");
        j = (typeof u === "string") ? e.trim(u) : "";
        j = j || window.location.href || "";
        if (j) {
            j = (j.match(/^([^#]+)/) || [])[1]
        }
        g = e.extend(true, {
            url: j,
            success: e.ajaxSettings.success,
            type: f || "GET",
            iframeSrc: /^https/i.test(window.location.href || "") ? "javascript:false" : "about:blank"
        }, g);
        var p = {};
        this.trigger("form-pre-serialize", [this, g, p]);
        if (p.veto) {
            d("ajaxSubmit: submit vetoed via form-pre-serialize trigger");
            return this
        }
        if (g.beforeSerialize && g.beforeSerialize(this, g) === false) {
```

Do you know how can i send_keys to that element? Is it complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can still try to use `send_keys` on `//input[@type='file']`. It's a bit weird that they've included the entire JS function for their file upload logic, but not uncommon. The `<input>` element should accept key strokes regardless.

You might also need to execute some JS to potentially reveal the element if this is hidden -- this is optional, but if just `send_keys` doesn't work then this might help:

```
# locate file input
file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

# optional: JS to reveal the element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].display = 'block';", file_input)

# send keys
file_input.send_keys("C:\Path\To\File")
```